# I need to get the penultimate result from a for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have an array of waypoints stored which have latitude and longitude values. I have created a for loop to loop through the array and compare my current CLLocation positions latitude and longitude to find which of the waypoints i am closest to. I also need to get the second closest waypoint and store this ac s a CLLocation object as well but cannot get it working.

The logic would be something like this

```
am I closest
     yes
move closest location to second closest
     set as second closest
loop again to get the closest point
```

My code:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

    //set latestlocation as the last object from the locations array
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

    //declare a closestpoint object
    CLLocation *closestWayPointToCurrentLocation;

    //declare a second closest point object
    CLLocation *secondClosestWayPointToCurrentLocation;

    //set the distance to a high number
    float distance = 10000000;
    float secondClosestWaypointDistance = 10000000;

    //load in plist
    NSString *plistName = [self.mapsInfo objectForKey:@"plistName"];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Chester" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plistName ofType:@"plist"];

    //store in array called waypoints
    NSArray *waypoints= [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

    //declare a variable for locationNum (the waypoints)
    int locationNum = 0;

    for (NSDictionary *point in waypoints) {
        CLLocation *waypointLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[(NSNumber *)[point  objectForKey:@"Lat"]floatValue] longitude:[(NSNumber *)[point objectForKey:@"Long"]floatValue]];

        float waypointDistanceFromCurrentLocation = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:waypointLocation];

        //secondClosestWayPointToCurrentLocation = waypointLocation;

        if(waypointDistanceFromCurrentLocation < distance) {
            //todo: move the current closestWayPointToCurrentLocation into second postion
            //update the second closest waypoint distance variable also with distance

            distance = waypointDistanceFromCurrentLocation;
            closestWayPointToCurrentLocation = waypointLocation;



            if(closestWayPointToCurrentLocation == waypointLocation) {

            }

        }
        else
        {
            //check against the second position
        //if closer than second position, replace it with new waypoint with code similar to above
        }
```

Comment: Please, format your code properly and don't abuse the `xcode` tag.

Comment: I have never used this site before. Can you clarify how code is expected to be formatted. Also I was unaware of my tag abuse - the project is in xcode.

Comment: Some general pieces of advice about code formatting: as I see, you should use somewhat more whitespace in order to make it easier to read and segmentate. Also, ALL CAPS is not welcome. The Xcode tag is inappropriate because the code, the error inside and its solution don't depend on the IDE. With regards to your question, using Xcode, Ecplipse, or not using any IDE at all don't make a difference.

Comment: I'n not very familiar with Obj-C, but I'd have thought that the NSArray would have some kind of method that would return the contents of the array at a particular index.  It should also have a method for turning how long the array is.  If you know how big the array is, and can read from any index, then you surely must be able to read from the Nth-1 index, or find the value of that index, and check the index you're in during a given iteration against the nth-1 index.

Comment: The waypoints in the array are scattered points on a map. The code loops through the array and checks the distance of our current location against each waypoint. The distance variable has been set to a high number so that the first if statement is satisfied on the first loop. It then updates the distance variable and loops again. It keeps doing this until the closest point to the current location is reached. This point could be in the middle of the array for all i know, so i dont think that Nth-1 would work. I might have to re word my original question

Comment: So I basically want the loop to stop at one point earlier than it currently is and return that waypoint, so I am left with the two closest points, rather than just the closest point which I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the point you is always the penultimate then you can retrive it like this

```
int totalNumberOfWaypoints = [waypoints count];

//Get penultimate waypoints
NSDictionary *penultimateWaypoint = [waypoints objectAtIndex:(totalNumberOfWaypoints - 2)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just make a sorted array of points, sorted by distance in ascending order?

```
NSMutableArray *waypoints= [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

    for (NSDictionary *point in waypoints) {


[waypoints sortUsingComparator: (NSComparisonResult) ^ (id obj1, id obj2) {
        CLLocation *waypointLocation1 = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[(NSNumber *)[obj1 objectForKey:@"Lat"]floatValue] longitude:[(NSNumber *)[obj1 objectForKey:@"Long"]floatValue]];
        CLLocation *waypointLocation2 = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[(NSNumber *)[obj2 objectForKey:@"Lat"]floatValue] longitude:[(NSNumber *)[obj2 objectForKey:@"Long"]floatValue]];

        float distance1 = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:waypointLocation1];
        float distance2 = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:waypointLocation2];

        if (distance1 < distance2) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        else if (distance1 > distance2) {
            return NSOrderedDescending
        }
        else
            return NSOrderedSame;

}];
```

This way you can always have the closest point at `[waypoints objectAtIndex:0]` and second closest point at `[waypoints objectAtIndex:1]` and so on.

less work, better result IMHO

Comment: If you don't use ARC remember to release waypointLocation1 and waypointLocation2 objects before you return result

Comment: Thanks pro_metedor that looks spot on. I'll try and implement it and let you know how I get on.

Comment: just to make sure im understanding this right, the code you've written will sort the array of waypoints every time the app loads based on the current location?

Comment: Cast of a block pointer to 'NSComparisonResult *' (aka 'enum NSComparisonResult *') is disallowed with ARC

Comment: This piece of code will sort the array by distance. It is your decision where you put it and when app will do it. It can be on every location check as this is most simple solution. For more efficient I would start monitoring map region and update this table when you exit that region.

Comment: Sending 'NSComparisonResult *' (aka 'enum NSComparisonResult *') to parameter of incompatible type 'NSComparator' (aka 'NSComparisonResult (^)(__strong id, __strong id)')

Comment: Found an easier solution. [waypoints removeObject:closestWayPointToCurrentLocation]; When it loops again it cannot reach the closest waypoint. Thanks for all of the suggestions